# automatic events occured on time in SQL ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net

i am developing a website and in this i want automatic SQL procedure call that will called after every 15 days...

is there any trigger or procedure that works for it or in ASP.net or vb.net to achieve the above task...

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a full (I.e. not express) version of SQL server then just use the SQL agent to schedule a job. If you are using an express edition then you can get around it by using the windows scheduler to run a batch file that fires your stored procedure